# Recursive function giving Segmentation fault

Tags: recursion, segmentation-fault

Problem: Write a program to find the sum of the given series 1+2+3+ . . . . . .(N terms)

why below code giving segmentation fault?

```
long long seriesSum(int n) {
        // code here
        
     if(n<=1){return n;}
     return((long long) n+ seriesSum( (long long)n-1));
    }
```

Comment: Which statement exactly is giving that error? Have you debugged?